# jquery YQL variable doesn't return value

Tags: jquery, variables, syntax, yql

Why does this not work for avgRent? The YQL console provides a value using this statement:

```
select * from html where url="http://www.zillow.com/widgets/zestimate/ZestimateSmallWidget.htm?did=zillow-shv-small-iframe-widget&type=iframe&forRent=true&address='5894+Dogwood+Cir+35111'" and xpath='//span[@id="zestimate-value"]'
```

But my code will not return a value. Could I be doing something wrong with the variable avgRent?

```
var postcode = $('#postcode').val();
            var address = $('#address').val();


            $.get(makeUrl('http://www.zillow.com/widgets/zestimate/ZestimateSmallWidget.htm?did=zillow-shv-small-iframe-widget&type=iframe&forRent=true&address=5894+Dogwood+Cir&csz=35111'),
                    function(data) {
                        var context = $('<div />').html($(data).find('content').text  ());

                        $('#avgRent').html($(context).find('span.zestimate-value').text());

                    });

                <tr>
    <td><strong>Average Monthly Rent: </strong></td>
                <td><div id="avgRent"></div></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: what does makeUrl return? a correctly formatted YQL request url? Are you sure it is correctly formatted?

Comment: I feel confident it is correctly formatted because I obtain a value using the yql console.

Comment: Add an ajax error handler and test all three arguments.

Comment: can you point me toward an example?